# Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [GADFullScreenAdViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crashlytics, google-ads-api

My Apps gets crash with following **Crashlytics** console description:

**Fatal Exception: UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation**

**Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [GADFullScreenAdViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES**

App supports all orientations except when a user switches player in fullscreen mode. I use a method in AppDelegate to manage supported orientations:

```
var supportedOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
   return self.supportedOrientation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Google AdMob Interstitial Ads. When the app makes ads request device may be in portrait orientation. So it gets ads in portrait orientation. When a user switches full-screen mode and ads events occur ads need portrait orientation but the application does not support it in full-screen mode so a crash is happening. To resolve this problem I need to check ads orientation and current device orientation.

Comment: How did you check the orientation of the ads? I don't think there's such API by AdMob to access it.

Comment: I store information about orientation when I make ads request.

Comment: The Api does not allow you to pass an orientation tho.